# How do I make a theme require Jquery (for anonymous users)?

Tags: 8, javascript

I'm creating a theme for D8 called 'herchel'.I'm trying to get this theme to require jquery on all pages (D8 doesn't load Jquery for anonymous users by default)

Looking through the [what little documentation i can find on d.o](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.libraries.yml/8) in addition to the core themes, I created a file called herchel.libraries.yml

I've tried the following... all with no luck:

```
drupal.herchel:
version: VERSION
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

-

```
drupal:
version: VERSION
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

-

```
herchel:
version: VERSION
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I need to put in this?

Comment: The third one is right, I think the problem is just whitespace - try indenting the line with `version` to match `dependencies`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran in to this upgrading one of my contrib themes to Drupal 8 as I wanted jquery.once for anonymous users. Here is what I did which works great:

In *herchel.libraries.yml*

```
herchel-corescripts:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/scripts.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
```

Then in your theme's *herchel.theme* file.

```
function herchel_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  // Render the library as laid out in herchel.libraries.yml
  $libraries['#attached']['library'][] = 'herchel/herchel-corescripts';
  \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($libraries);
}
```

Pay mind to the indenting as well for the YML code. Though it's not really documented that well yet, you can have a look at this issue and its change log.

[Replace hook_library_info() by *.libraries.yml file](https://drupal.org/node/1996238)

Note that you also see a theoretical theme's "scripts.js" file in the code above but you may not need it. In my theme, that's what uses jquery to call custom code.

[This code](https://drupal.org/comment/8507583#comment-8507583) is probably a good reference too for the YML bits. Note that in both cases `version` is at the same level as `dependencies`.

I also [made a list of Drupal 8 issues](https://drupal.org/project/gratis#d8) I encountered and took part in with my D8 upgrade.

***Update:***

I've fixed the code, we ran in to this issue: [Replace #attached library array values with provider-namespaced strings](https://drupal.org/node/2203407)

Note this:

```
 $libraries['#attached']['library'][] = array('herchel', 'herchel-corescripts');
```

vs.this

```
$libraries['#attached']['library'][] = 'herchel/herchel-corescripts';
```

I tested and the errors went away. :)

Comment: Danny, you're awesome! But, I'm getting some PHP errors.

    Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in _drupal_add_library() (line 2676 of core\includes\common.inc).
    Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in drupal_get_library() (line 2741 of core\includes\common.inc).

These errors appear regardless of what's in the herchel.libraries.yml file. I tried working around it a bit with no luck.

I also tried your code from Gratis but that appears to be before [issue 8507583](https://drupal.org/comment/8507583#comment-8507583) was commited

Comment: $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'libraryprovider/libraryname';

Comment: Mike, the new code in Gratis is in the dev version only (http://drupalcode.org/project/gratis.git/tree/refs/heads/8.x-1.x ) and I tested it and it works with the latest Alpha of D8. I am pretty much heads down on a project today but I may be able to help this weekend. What version of D8 are you using?

Comment: How can achieve this without using a preprocess function ?

Answer (score 11):

In your theme create libraries file `herchel.libraries.yml`. Into this file put:

```
libname:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/scripts.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

In `herchel.info.yml` put:

```
libraries:
  - herchel/libname
```

Comment: There was an [issue](https://drupal.org/node/1813186) about this and it's fixed at Drupal Developer Days in Szeged.

Comment: I've updated and tested the code in my answer, this is more likely the issue we ran in to based on the error message. https://drupal.org/node/2203407

Comment: Maybe this will also help... Documentation page about libraries implementation https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have add spaces before "dependencies:"

this is true:

```
google-maps:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    vendor/gmap3.js: {cope: footer}
    //maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=000000: { type: external, cope: footer}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

for example this is wrong:

```
google-maps:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    vendor/gmap3.js: {cope: footer}
    //maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=000000: { type: external, cope: footer}
    dependencies:
      - core/jquery
      - core/drupal
      - core/drupalSettings
```