# Javascript not loading in all links of the site

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with this javascript error on my page for days.

Everytime I access the site as anonymous, I can click and access links but I'm getting a white screen and I believe this is because the site does not recognise or call its javascript. My main.js should load the animation on path: css/animsition.min.css.

This is the line where I'm getting the error.

```
$(".animsition").animsition({
```

When I am logged in as user, this error never shows up and site is fine.
Attached image is the chrome console result.

[image: This is my console error results.]

Comment: Check is not due caching. Disable al caching and test again. Also, check in inspector's network tab if any file is missing when accessing as anonymous (404 or even 403).

Comment: This sounds similar to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109023/how-do-i-make-a-drupal-8-theme-require-jquery-for-anonymous-users

Comment: And also https://www.webomelette.com/drupal-8-core-javascript-files-anonymous-users

Comment: Thanks @Magick. Really your a life saver. That's solved my issue. :D